# How does '@method Address setCollectShippingRates(int $value)' work?

Tags: magento2.2, methods

Magento 2.2, Clsss 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address'. I cannot find body of method 'setCollectShippingRates()'.

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;


/**
 * Sales Quote address model
 *
 * @api
 * ................
 * @method Address setCollectShippingRates(int $value)
 **/
 class Address extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress   implements
\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface
{
  .............
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into parent class which extend from **\Magento\Framework\DataObject** that means some method definition no needed. **setCollectShippingRates** and **getCollectShippingRates** one of them. If you don't want to collect rate some quote operation just use following way:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->collectTotals()
```

Comment: I added this code:

    '$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $shippingAddress->collectShippingRates();'

I got error: 

    '"message": "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'False\\MyClass\\true''